# Apagar um diretório recursivamente

Tags: c#, .net

Observando a documentação da Microsoft sobre o método `System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, bool);`eu notei que adicionando um booleano verdadeiro no segundo parâmetro ele se torna recursivo.

No meu caso, a pasta que irei deletar contém arquivos sendo utilizados por outros processos e alguns arquivos somente leitura e/ou protegidos pelo sistema operacional. Eventualmente, o meu aplicativo irá retornar um `IOException`. Como eu posso ignorar todos os arquivos que não podem ser excluídos? Atualmente a minha aplicação trava na metade do processo sem excluir todos os arquivos possíveis...

Comment: Lá não está deletando, mas é a mesma coisa para tratar o erro.

Comment: Percorrer todos os arquivos da pasta em um **<foreach>** e para cada um deles usar um bloco de try/catch com o tratamento correto da IOException não resolve?

Comment: Daniel, resolver até resolve, mas eu queria utilizar o próprio metodo da System.IO